# Marketing Cloud: Using Publications Lists to Update Salesforce Contact

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, list, sfmc-business-unit

I am leveraging Publication Lists in Marketing Cloud to manage unsubs from unique Business Units so that a contact can choose to unsubscribe from one business unit but not all. I also need this to be reflected in Salesforce as well, so sales reps are able to see which business units they can reach out to a contact about.

I've created a custom multi-select SF Contact field that I am trying to update via a Journey Builder, where the business units (Publication Lists) are the field options, but can't figure out how to bring in Publication List subscribers to a Journey to make the update.

My understanding of Marketing Cloud is very elementary, so I could be going about this all wrong. Could someone point me in the right direction for how to best solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Journey Builder does not support the use of lists created in the Salesforce Marketing Cloud Email application. As a workaround, you can create a journey specific data extension from publication list via query activity. Run a query on publication list and populate the data extension. You can use this data extension as an entry source for your journey and then you can update the custom field value on your SF contact.

Comment: This worked great, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, but still relevant. That previous message was copypasted from the official documentation, which refers to Subscribers Lists, such as All Subscribers, and not Publication Lists: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000386679&type=1

You can easily associate Publication Lists to each Email Activity inside a Journey through the UI: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_jb_managing_contacts.htm&type=5